# how to access the value of status attribute

Tags: jquery

Okay sorry but this is now n Two tiered question.

How do I traverse from `Riversdale` to `Western Cape`
and
how to access the value of status attribute (which I think was already answered)

but Now selecting the correct attribute is a slight problem.

`entry = $(this).closest('.expandListContentRow div:nth-child(1)').attr('id');`

entry gives me the correct id, but I want to access the `status` attribute.

`<div class="expandListItem highlight" id="b82e107" status="deactivated">Sandy Bay</div>`

How do I get the value of the Status attribute?

This might give you the idea of the list in which I want to traverse

```
<div class="expandListContentRow contentCol2" id="28fa1d89" style="display: block;">
    <div class="expandListItem addNewProv" id="SouthAfrica_button">ADD NEW PROVINCE</div>
    <div class="expandListItem b82e107e highlight" id="b82e107e" status="deactivated">Western Cape</div>
    <div class="expandListContent_sub1">
        <div class="expandListContentRow_sub1 contentCol_sub1 SUB_b82e107e" id="b82e107e" style="display: block;">
            <div class="expandListItem_sub1 addNewCity" id="Antalia_button">ADD NEW CITY</div>
            <div class="expandListItem_sub1 highlight_sub" id="429973ea" status="deactivated">Riversdale</div>
            <div class="expandListItem_sub1" id="b71e53aa" status="deactivated">Ashton</div>
            <div class="expandListItem_sub1" id="a3fcad14" status="deactivated">Cape Town</div>
            <div class="expandListItem_sub1" id="5dcbf222" status="deactivated">Somerset West</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if I want to activate `Riversdale` I need to activate the parent as-well, `Western Cape` in this instance. Ive clearly traversed wrong before, so How do you get from `Riversdale` to `Western Cape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass attribute name in `.attr()` to get the value. you are having duplicate IDs for some elements. which is wrong. also you have incorrect selector to target desired div. use:

```
entry = $(this).closest('.expandListContent_sub1').prev().attr('status');
```

You should note that using non-spec attributes in your HTML will render your page invalid. Use a data-* attribute instead:

**DOM:**

```
<div class="expandListItem highlight" id="b82e107" data-status="deactivated">Sandy Bay</div>
```

**JS:**

```
entry = $(this).closest('.expandListContent_sub1').prev().data('status');
```

Comment: mmm Okay, maybe Im not at the right palce after traversing. Thanks for the help, I will be using this, just need to make sure about my traversing.

Comment: share the dom and what is the context of `$(this)`. its not possible to help without that.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the same with `attr()` attribute.

```
 entry = $(this).closest('.expandListContentRow div:nth-child(1)').attr('id');
 var status = $(this).closest('.expandListContentRow div:nth-child(1)').attr('status');
```

**however for porper w3c validation use html5 data attribute instead.**

```
 <div class="expandListItem highlight" id="b82e107" data-status="deactivated">Sandy Bay</div>

 $(this).closest('.expandListContentRow div:nth-child(1)').data('status');
```

Comment: mmm Okay, maybe Im not at the right palce after traversing. Thanks for the help, I will be using this, just need to make sure about my traversing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other this should work

```
 $('.expandListItem').attr('status');
```

but as you not getting the desired result,so do

```
console.log($(this))
console.log($(this).closest('.expandListContentRow'))
console.log($(this).closest('.expandListContentRow div:nth-child(1)'))
```

to check where the issue is.Hope that helps